# Possible to run a cron task using external script?

Tags: product, cron, external

i want to run product alert using external script, by default, the product alert run once a date, so i can't test the email (transactional template)

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalog_product_alert>
            <run>
                <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
            </run>
        </catalog_product_alert>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

is it possbile to run this job using external script?

Answer (score 3):

Miraculously i done that

change protected function to public

```
public function processStock(Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Email $email)
```

use external script

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$app = Mage::getModel('productalert/observer');
$email = Mage::getModel('productalert/email');

$app->processStock($email);
?>
```

this is just for test purpose, restore to protected after test done

Comment: also,you can use `Mage :: app( "default" );
Mage::getModel('productalert/observer')->process();  `

Answer (score 1):

Yes! you don't need to create an external endpoint, just create a simple module and set `<Mage_ProductAlert/>` as dependency then in your `etc/config.xml` overwrite the cronjob declaration that way:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalog_product_alert>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>productalert/observer::process</model>
            </run>
        </catalog_product_alert>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

In this example the process method will run every minute (but still depends on the frequency of your system cronjob).